# how to stop user to posting duplicate or same answers

Tags: discussion, support

how to encourage user to upvote answers not to post duplicate or same answers. like in this example [How to remove Size filter section from layered navigation in magento 1.9.01](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114017/how-to-remove-size-filter-section-from-layered-navigation-in-magento-1-9-01)  . I am seeing three identical answers. how we can stop this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I will do in this case is, make a comment on later answer to indicate that this is just a duplicate and downvote it. Then wait for two days.

If the answerer responds and edit his answer with additional point, then I will upvote that answer (because previous down-vote has no relevance then).

If he/she didn't respond, then I flag it to moderator to close by indicating this is just a mirror.

But remember, if the answer posses at least one simple additional information, then I don't like to discourage it.

Other than this, I don't think there is any other dedicated solution for this.

Comment: thanks for solution.